# How can I bypass the redirection in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, angular2-routing

I use Angular 2 and I am writing Protractor tests. My problem is that when user puts the username and the password and click the login button page redirects to a middle page and that middle page redirects to another page that gives and validate the JWT (after login button user doesn't need to do anything till the page reaches to the dashboard) **but protractor cannot do the redirection**. Is there a way to put Protractor in sleep till I reach out the dashboard? or is there a way that you can suggest?

`browser.sleep(10000)` didn't work. Because as browser sleeps protractor stays on the login page till it fail.

Error message:

```
Expected Function to equal 'http://localhost:4200'.
Expected :"http://localhost:4200"
Actual   :{}
```

Comment: what do you mean with protractor not doing the redirect? so you want a test to confirm it is actually passing through the middle page? or just test the final destination page?

Comment: @eLRuLL test the final destination because middle page has a different URL and middle page redirects me to another page which has a different URL with JWT but as a user you cannot click anywhere in that page it is like a security check

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.then` on every promise or else promises will resolve after all the synchronous tasks are complete.

```
browser.sleep(10000).then(() => {
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {
        expect(url).toEqual('http://localhost:4200');
    });
})
```

Ideally, you want to use `browser.wait()` to wait until the url is as expected before moving on. This way, it won't wait 10000ms, but it will complete the wait right when the url matches.

```
let timeout = 10000;
browser.wait(() => {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {
        return url === 'http://localhost:4200';
    });
}, timeout).thenCatch(err => {
    throw err;
});
```

Of course, this is just speculation on what you haven't done/need to do since you need to post your code.

Edit: Further explaination. If you run this:

```
console.log('Got here 1');
browser.sleep(0).then(() => {
   console.log('Got here 2');
]);
console.log('Got here 3');
```

You would probably expect the output to be:

```
Got here 1
Got here 2
Got here 3
```

But the output would actually be:

```
Got here 1
Got here 3
Got here 2
```

Because "promises will resolve after all the synchronous tasks are complete"

Comment: The second solution that you provided throws me another error that is as follows:

`Failed: protractor_1.browser.wait(...).thenCatch is not a function
TypeError: protractor_1.browser.wait(...).thenCatch is not a function`

--------------------------------------
First solution doesn't work either it redirects me back to my login page and I need to login again.

Comment: Instead of using `thenCatch`, use `catch` instead. That redirect back to login page, that is weird behavior. I don't see how what I wrote can cause a redirect. Post your code and we can actually help.

Comment: what you wrote is perfect, that's what I tried too, the problem is that as I said, it doesn't go to the page that middle page redirects to so it cannot get JWT token and it never really signs up so, waiting doesn't solve the problem, it tries to go to the main page but because it is not signed up, main page redirects me back to the login page because it has auth guard

Comment: Are you using `.then` on everything that is a promise? If you post your steps and code, I would be able to help, but at this point, I can only speculate.